# How to namespace forkJoin in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How do I namespace each observable for forkJoin in rxjs

for example

```
Observable.forkJoin([observable1, observable2])
```

would be like

```
// This does not work
Observable.forkJoin({'1': observable1, '2': observable2})
```

Comment: I believe there's no way to do that.. You will receive back data as an Array containing result for each observable.

Answer (score 0):

From [forkJoin - learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

> signature: forkJoin(...args, selector : function): Observable

so the selector can add additional info

```
const selector = (x, y) => {
  return { '1': x, '2': y };
}

Observable.forkJoin([observable1, observable2], selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more "Rx" approach you can use something like this:

```
const sources = {
    'a': Observable.of(1),
    'b': Observable.of(42),
    'c': Observable.of(3),
};

const keys = Object.keys(sources);

Observable.forkJoin(Object.values(sources))
    .mergeMap(results => Observable.zip(keys, Observable.from(results)))
    .toArray()
    .map(pairs => pairs.reduce((object, pair) => {
        object[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        return object;
    }, {}))
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Which prints:

```
{ a: 1, b: 42, c: 3 }
```

See live demo: http://jsbin.com/xijonem/7/edit?js,console